# Left hand side USB-C ports on 2017 MBP 15" blocked

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, hardware

Ive got a 2017 15" Macbook Pro.

This model has 4x USB C ports (2 on each side) which can be used for pretty much anything from charging to connecting to an external display (as long as you have the right adaptors).

Recently the 2 ports on the left hand side of the computer wont allow you to connect anything in there, you can put a USB-C male end in, but it will only go about 2/3rds in. My guess is that they have come ever so slightly mis-aligned with the aluminium frame of the computer.

Has anyone seen or heard of this issue before ? Do you know how i can fix it ?

Comment: If you are not familiar with working in laptops, your best bet is taking it to an Apple store or an Apple Authorized service provider for repair. Otherwise fixit.com has guides to upgrading and repairing Macs and other computers and electronics.

Comment: Im somewhat familiar with working with laptops, ive done lots of battery, HD, ram, fan etc.. swaps etc.. over the years to macs (both desktops and laptops) although the scope of this has become more and more limited as apple locks down its hardware.

Answer (score 1):

The Thunderbolt ports are not part of the main logic board, so you would reconnect and/or [replace that component](https://www.ifixit.com/Store/Mac/MacBook-Pro-Retina-A1706-A1707-Late-2016-2017-USB-C-Board/IF123-071) to remedy both not working on the same side of the Mac.

Apple is doing the opposite of locking down their hardware recently. The design of them requiring skill to repair happened during the PPC to Intel transition, and they’ve steadily been adding more third party repair options and even DIY parts and guides and tool rentals.

Your model won’t likely get an official repair guide, but this is not a challenging repair since it’s not dealing with a glued part like the battery or the Touch ID. Removing the part also allows the best chance to remove any debris or mis-alignment and inspect the physical condition of the ports. A lighted magnifier can also be used before you open the case as it might show many types of potential obstruction.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons that the male part of the USB Type-C port is only going in 2/3rd of the way in would be because of accumulation of some dirt or debris that is not blocking the port & obstructing the connector from going all the way in. The best way to check it is to see it under the light and if there is gunk then clean it with tweezers or toothpicks.

If not and then you see that there is a slight physical damage then please do that it to the genius bar to get it checked.

Comment: Be very careful with electrical shorting or damaging the pins with tools.

Comment: if illuminated using a flash light - is it possible to determine wether there is some debris or misalignment causing the problem?